# Missing Telerik files in project\obj upon window store app package creation

Tags: telerik, uwp, telerik-grid, uwp-xaml

I've been working on an UWP app with a Telerik RadDataGrid component on it. It builds fine in debug and release mode. However, when building the windows store app package the process fails with the following reason:

ErrorFor file "C:\Projects\CompanyAppClient10\obj\x64\Debug\PackageLayout\Telerik.UI.Xaml.Grid.UWP\Assets\FilterFlyout\ic_arrow_down_white.scale-140.png" - 
0x80070003 - The system cannot find the path specified.CompanyAppClient10 C:\Projects\CompanyAppClient10\MakeAppx

What could be the cause of this?

I've already tried creating a new clean UWP application with only a RadDataGrid component on MainPage.xaml. This results in the same error as above.

I've also repaired my Telerik UWP installation. Makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the newer update fixes it.

Alternatively you can use the following workaround -- copy the entire folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for Universal Windows Platform Q2 2016\Binaries\Telerik.UI.Xaml.Grid.UWP\Assets\FilterFlyout

into

C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for Universal Windows Platform Q2 2016\SDKs\Telerik UI for Universal Windows Platform\Redist\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Telerik.UI.Xaml.Grid.UWP\Assets

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message my guess is that your app requires scale 140 assets but Telerik doesn’t provide them. You many want to contact Telerik directly and file a bug report.